# PHP image() works locally but fails silently on remote host

Tags: php, image, png, gd

This script fetches file data from a file and creates an image then sends it to the browser, on my local server it runs perfectly but when I upload it remotely, it fails silently. I've slimmed the script down to the following and it still fails. I've verified that the file exists, is readable and is a `png` file

Why is this happening?

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $image->data = file_get_contents('image.png');
    $image->image = imagecreatefromstring($image->data);
    imagepng($image->image);
    imagedestroy($image->image);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

This is most-likely because you are not instantiating a new `stdClass` object before using it here...

```
$image->data = file_get_contents('image.png');
$image->image = imagecreatefromstring($image->data);
```

While this will work, it will throw a warning. Your local server probably has `display_errors` turned off whereas the production machine would have `display_errors` turned on. This would prepend the warning to the image text and cause the image to fail.

To fix this just instantiate a new object before using it for the first time

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$image = new stdClass();  // this creates a new base object

$image->data = file_get_contents('image.png');
$image->image = imagecreatefromstring($image->data);
imagepng($image->image);
imagedestroy($image->image);
```